# Expo React Native App Not Loading the AppEntry.bundle

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am working on a react-native app using expo. The app was working just fine. I could do npm start to run the metro builder and then run my app on simulator as well as iOS devices directly.

I did 2 things.

1. I upgraded the expo version to latest - 3.17.15
2. I rebooted my laptop.

After these 2 changes, I could still do npm start without any issues. But, when I tried to open/ run the app in iOS simulator it got stuck at the bundle loading. In fact it could not get the bundle file only.

I thought this was a network problem where the simulator/ device was not able to reach http://127.0.0.1:19000 However, when I visited the url in the browser that was working.

The bunlde url that I saw in the error: 
[image: Here's what I see after waiting for 2 minutes]

Now, when I try to visit that bundle url through the simulator:

http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle

The browser never loads the thing and times out.

I have already tried:

1. Cleaning the cache - npm start --reset-cache
2. Deleting the .expo folders in ~/.expo as well as ~/project/.expo
3. Changing the mode from Lan -> Tunnel.
4. Upgrading the global expo-cli to latest version.
5. removing the node_modules directory in the project ~/project/node_modules
6. re installing the node_modules by doing - npm install.

IMPORTANT - After having this issue with my current app, I decided to spawn a new blank expo app and run the same. Same result. The bundle was not loaded. I also remember something like this happening to me in the past but don't remember how I fixed it.

My Network is a hotspot through my phone. The same network used to work until yesterday without any issues. So not sure if reboot has caused some setting to revert.

Any help troubleshooting this problem would be very helpful here.

[image: Here's what I see when I visit the url : http://127.0.0.1:19000/]

[image: Here's my metro builder log:]

Comment: do scanning QR code works?

Comment: Nope. So I read somewhere that I could change the mode to tunnel from lan and it will work. But neither works.

Comment: the problem is with the expo, Expo had a new update few days ago, Is your SDK and CLI up to date and on the same version?

Comment: Yes. SDK - 37. Expo expo-cli@3.17.16. 

Is there a way to find out easily if the bundle is generated successfully. Because when I do the web - It does open the app in web.. not everything works. which is ok. But the app opens.

Comment: Also here's some more additional information:

After starting the expo app in debug mode I do get the request for the AppEntry.bundle 



::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2020:05:29:25 +0000] "GET /node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Expo/2.15.3.10122 CFNetwork/1125.2 Darwin/19.4.0"

Comment: Thanks @UA_ Finally I solved it. See the answer below.

Comment: Glad you solved

Answer (score 1):

Finally after spending 2 days and working on 2 different laptops I could get to the root of this problem.

Firstly, I thought this was an OS upgrade issue (I upgraded my OS to Mac OS Catalina). So, I cloned my repo on another laptop, a fresh one where these was no node expo or react native. I initialized a new expo typescript react native project. Tried to run it - Worked like a charm. Simulator was not installed but worked on my device without any issues. The metro bundle log was generated.

This was leading me even closer to my assumption. So I tried to revert all the changes I had in my repo and tried building the app with `npm start` which eventually runs `expo start`. Did not work.

Finally - I created a fresher user on my laptop. The upgraded one. Cloned the repo - and tried to build the project. This time! Again it failed, however there was one change - in the metro builder log I got a this error:

```
2020-04-06T21:29:57,075: [0x110e7fdc0] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/shrikant-state: Permission denied
```

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2020-04-06T21:29:57,075: [0x110e7fdc0] while computing sockname: failed to create /usr/local/var/run/watchman/shrikant-state: Permission denied

To solve that I just changed the permission to the watchman directory:

```
sudo chmod 042777  /usr/local/var/run/watchman/
```

The app was finally built and running successfully on both the simulator and the device!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into something similar, I was stuck on this and it turned out expo didn't like me using a logical OR assignment ( ||= ) even though typescript and my linters were fine with it. I replaced my ||= with a ternary and worked fine.